# Create Aggregation query using Spring MongoDB | Add hours into Date in Projection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I want to create an Aggregation query in my spring boot application.

Query:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
{ 
  $match : { 
    timeStamp: {$gte: ISODate("2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2020-07-13T23:59:59.000Z")} 
  }
},
{ "$project": {
      "h":{"$hour": { "$add": [ "$timeStamp", 5.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ] }}
  }},
{ "$group":{
      "_id": "$h",
      "total":{ "$sum": 1}
  }
}
)
```

I've created following Aggregation object in my spring boot application

```
Aggregation violationHourlyData = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("timeStamp").gte(fromDate).lte(toDate)),
                        Aggregation.project("_id").andExpression( "hour(timeStamp)").as("h"),
                        Aggregation.group("h").count().as("count")
                );
```

In the above object, I want to add some time in timeStamp as mentioned in the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by understanding andExpression() in detail.

**Answer:**

```
Aggregation violationHourlyData = Aggregation.newAggregation(
         Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("timeStamp").gte(fromDate).lte(toDate)),
         Aggregation.project("_id").andExpression(  "hour(add(timeStamp, 5.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000))").as("h"),
         Aggregation.group("h").count().as("count")
                );
```